# Вылезает ошибка при использовании функции pop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Смысл программы, задавать пользователю вопросы на время
Чтобы вопросы не повторялись я решил использовать функцию pop
Ошибка вылетает по принципу русской рулетки в любой момент
Вот и сама ошибка:

> IndexError: pop index out of range

А вот и сам код:

```
import random
import time
questions = ['Каким словом называли в древние времена водяные часы?','Именно эта страна дарит Великобритании красивую ель на Рождество. Какая?','Расширение мониторов меряют в …', 'Как называется линия, у которой нет концов?', 'Кем был Чингисхан?', 'Что в море является ориентиром для моряка?']
answers = {0:'Клепсидра',1:'Норвегия',2:'пикселях',3:'Луч',4:'ханом',5:'Полярная звезда'}
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
def timequestion():
    points = 0
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        rand_index = numbers.pop(random.choice(numbers))
        print('На ответ даётся 10 секунд')
        question = questions[rand_index]
        print(question)
        right_answer = answers[rand_index]

        stop = time.time()
        answer = input('Введите ответ:')
        if answer.lower()== right_answer.lower():
            if stop - start > 10:
                print('Время истекло')
                continue
            else:
                print('Ответ верный!')
                points += 1
            continue
        else:
            print('Ответ неверен!')
            continue
    print('Вы набрали ' + str(points))
timequestion()
```

Comment: Ну у вас же всё меньше элементов остаётся в `numbers`, а у вас там номера то любые могут оставаться, например, 5. И что будет, если в `numbers` останется 1 элемент, и это будет номер 5? Лучше сделайте списку `random.shuffle` и потом делайте из него просто `numbers.pop()` и всё. Будут случайные номера, все, и без проблем.

Comment: в пикселях - разрешение, а не расширение, а у луча есть один конец. Он называется начало.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `pop` изымает элемент по индексу, а не по значению, на что вы судя по всему рассчитывали.
Вы можете сделать так:

```
def timequestion():
    points = 0
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        rand_index = random.choice(numbers)
        numbers.remove(rand_index)
        ...
```

Или как предложил [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf) в [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1413789/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-pop/1413815#comment2515568_1413789):

```
def timequestion():
    points = 0
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        rand_index = numbers.pop()
        ...
```